# Alert Dialog listview length

Tags: java, android, listview, android-dialog

I want to set the `AlertDialog` to be the length of `ListView` inside, the `AlertDialog` has a button on the bottom, and currently is spans the entire screen even if the list contains 1 or 2 items, how could I achieve this,

here is my code so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lvItemsSelected"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonOk"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="OK"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this can help you, try to call this method after filling data to ListView

```
public void getListViewSize(ListView myListView, Context context) {
    ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();

    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {

        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup)
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        int listViewWidth = screenWidth - 65;
        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listViewWidth,
                View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        listItem.measure(widthSpec, 0);

        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    myListView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: Thank but I need it to be relative and inside the XML file

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use a `ConstraintLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout` and then link the constraints of the `AlertDialog` to the width of the `ListView`

Comment: I kinda have it working, but now the button is on top of the list, rather then under it. How could I fix that?

Comment: You mentioned below that the layout has to be relative. why is that?

Comment: When you hover over the top of your alert window, you will see that a small circle appears. You can drag that circle to any side of another object to "link" its position to the other object

Comment: Sorry thats wrong, but I do need the button to be under the list

Comment: drag the button underneath the list and connect the dot on the upper side of the button towards the dot on the lower side of the list

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work, how could i attach it to the bottom of listview in xml

Comment: Are you in the design view? Just google constraint layout, and  you'll find out how it works